# How to import third line only in oracle using sql loader or external table

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper, external-tables

I have this data to load in to  oracle i use external table concept to load the data .
any idea how to load only the third line from the source  ?

This is the data in txt externally located

ENG,England,English
SCO,Scotland,English
IRE,Ireland,English
WAL,Wales,Welsh

Comment: Why bother to go to all this effort to import 1 row?  Just write an insert statement, no?

Comment: for example if i have 10000 lines and they asked me to upload only one line of data  from  5000th line or 5000th row.?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO <target_table>
SELECT * FROM <external_table>
WHERE  <condition to determine which line to import>
```

ie.  country_code (or whatever column is called) = 'ENG', etc.

Comment: i want the lines of data from row 5000 to 6000 then i how should i do the import

Answer (score 0):

{OPTIONS (SKIP = 1000, LOAD=40050 ,ERRORS = 2147483647)

LOAD INTO TABLE @table_name}

SQL LOADER:  You can try this - SKIP records  and LOAD how many records you need

Comment: `SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 1.
Illegal combination of non-alphanumeric characters
{OPTIONS (SKIP = 1, LOAD=40050 ,ERRORS = 2147483647)`
^  [https://infoallsite.wordpress.com/2016/05/14/sql-loader-error/]
i got this error any idea on this one ?